# What is the difference between the following two LinkedinAPI calls for fetching Ad Accounts of a user?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

There are 2 call end points given by the Linkedin API

1. v2/adAccountsV2?q=search
2. v2/adAccountUsersV2?q=authenticatedUser

that are used to fetch ad Accounts of a user. What is the difference between the two although the purpose of those two seems the same?Are there any benefits of one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

**Ad Account Users API** allows to manage user access to Ad Accounts, read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-account-users).

**Ad Accounts API** is mainly for Enterprise or Business Ads Account holders, not personals.

When it stands to fetching Ad Accounts by some criteria then those methods performs different jobs and returns different JSON data structure.

If you want to retrieve the business Ad Accounts by ID, name, reference, type, and status fields then you can use `/v2/adAccountsV2?q=search` call and append to it all the required parameters. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-accounts).

If you require to find Ad Accounts by an authenticated user then you will need to call `/v2/adAccountUsersV2?q=authenticatedUser` and it will return the Ad Accounts associated with a member whose access token is being passed for the API call.